# What's the difference between <T> T vs T in the return type of a method?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method, like this,

```
public <T> T doSomething(Class<T> T) {
return T.newInstance();
}
```

I can also do the same like this,

```
public T doSomething(Class<T> T) {
return T.newInstance();
}
```

Is there any difference between these two? Please ignore T.newInstance(), I'm basically going to create a new instance of T somehow and return it.

thanks,
sam

Answer (score 9):

> What's the difference between `<T> T` vs `T` in the return type of a method?

There is no `<T> T`. The `<T>` is not part of the return type; it's a separate thing, indicating the type parameter. (You can also have `public <T> void ...`.)

In the version with `<T>`, you're declaring `T` as a type parameter of the method, and the `T` in the argument and the return-type are referring to that type parameter.

In the version without `<T>`, you're *not* declaring `T` as a type parameter of the method, so it's most likely a type parameter of the containing class or another containing scope. (Alternatively, someone may have named an actual class or interface `T`, in which case you should give that person a talking-to.)

If both versions compile, then the second is probably the one you want: you probably want to be using the class's type parameter `T`, rather than adding a new one that hides it. (And if you really do want a new type parameter unrelated to your class's type parameter, then you should use a new name for it to avoid confusion.)

Comment: `class T<T>{ <T> T T(T T){ return T; } }`

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, you declare a generic method `doSomething` with its own type parameter `<T>`.  If it's in a generic class, then this `<T>` is separate from any type parameters that the class may have (even another `<T>`!).

In the second example, you don't declare a generic type parameter on `doSomething`.  If the class defines `<T>`, then this method simply uses it.  If it doesn't, then `T` is unrecognized and a compiler error results.

Answer (score 0):

Second option will work only if T is declared as a class generic type. If class doesn't define  any generic type and only its member function accepts/returns generic type , you need to explicitly declare it in function declaration.